# Reading JSON files: may this solution cause a memory leak?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm writing some tests using Jest and I wrote a "mock factory" function that reads a JSON file using require(). But when I need more than one copy, it have to create a deep copy parsing the original var so a I can manipulate the objects separately.

```
export function createFoo(): Foo {
  const foo: Foo = require('./foo.json');
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));
}
```

I call this function in almost all tests. I read some tips and examples here but I still got some questions. Isn't there a better way to solve that issue than stringfying and then parsing again? Do I have to free the require return to avoid memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a concern here. You have room to optimize your code though:

```
const fooString = JSON.stringify(require('./foo.json'));

export function createFoo(): Foo {
  return JSON.parse(fooString);
}
```